# Does Android store information about previous SIM cards?

Tags: gps, privacy, sim-card

Does Android store any info about previous SIM cards that have been inserted into the phone?
Can the current mobile operator access this info?

Can the current mobile operator get my GPS location when I'm abroad or after I return?
Is it information stored anywhere?

Comment: As far as I know the Android device itself doe snot store old locations, however if you have enabled localization via Wifi the device communicates with Google and checks the reachable Wifi networks and their location. Additionally your network operator knows your position most likely in case the phone was not in Airplane mode (because of the cell towers you were connected while abroad).

Comment: @Robert what about sim cards? 
So if I turn that off and pull sim cards out my current carrier can't track anything?